# Regex Replace 406 with 401

Tags: regex

In the following example, I am trying to replace the 00406 and the 004060 with 00401 and 004010 using Regex Replacer. I can't get it to work. I don't have a lot of experience with Regex. Where is the error?

Find - (ISA*\d\d*.*?).*00406|\?|004060|

Replace - \1*00401|~|004010|~

ISA*00*          *00*          *14*0123456789100  *12*9876543218     *151130*0913*|*00406*000000303*0*P*>~
GS*FA*1234567890100*9876543218*20151130*0913*245*X*004060~

Comment: `*` matches a sequence of characters, I think you'll have to escape it.

Comment: Why are you using Regex to accomplish this instead of a simple [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work in my application. I'm in a BizTalk ACDEnhancedPipeline. I have one line for the search, and one line for the replace.